# Does anybody else encounter issues with the new Flexslider 2.3.0 library and Drupal?

Tags: 7, javascript

After installing the most recent version of the flexslider library (`2.3.0`) the Drupal Flexslider module (`7.x-2.0-alpha3`) is not able to find the flexslider library anymore.

I get the following error on `admin/reports/status`:

**FlexSlider version could not be determined. Please consult the README.txt for installation instructions.**

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the most recent version does not work with the Drupal flexslider module. I **downgraded** the flexslider JS library to version `2.2.2` and the flexslider Drupal module got recognized.

I used the following JS library version of [flexslider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/archive/version/2.2.2.tar.gz) ... here you can find all [releases](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/releases)